# Docker with monorepos - sharing files between subrepos

Tags: docker

I've got a monorepo with various Node apps in subfolders (using Lerna, but applies to all monorepos). Every subfolder has its own Dockerfile. However, to be built, every app needs a file (tsconfig.json) from the root of the project... which is outside of the "build context".

What's the best way to solve this issue?

I could run `docker build` from the root of the project, but then

- all paths in Dockerfiles would have to accomodate that
- During the build phase of every single application, the entire monorepo (everything in the context) would be sent to Docker.

This one, obviously, doesn't work.

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /some/src/path
COPY ../../tsconfig.build.json ../..
RUN yarn build
```